# Insert a list into another list given a position P. Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to finish a prolog exercise, I have half of it but I need something more to finish it, that is the reason I am asking for help.
What I need is an small prolog program, given two lists (`L1`, `L2`) and one position as `P`, insert the first list into the second one and store that list in a third list (`L3`). 
`insert_at(L1,L2,P,L3)`

Here an example:

```
?- insert_at ([h1,h2], [a1,a2,a3,a4], 2,L3).
L3 = [a1,h1,h2,a2,a3,a4]
```

The code I have for this is this one:

```
remove_at(X,[X|Xs],1,Xs).
remove_at(X,[Y|Xs],K,[Y|Ys]) :-
    K > 1, 
    K1 is K - 1,
    remove_at(X,Xs,K1,Ys).
insert_at(X,L,K,R) :- remove_at(X,R,K,L).
```

What I get is this:

```
?- insert_at([h1,h2],[a1,a2,a3,a4],2,L3).

L3 = [a1, [h1, h2], a2, a3, a4] % What I get

L3 = [a1, h1, h2, a2, a3, a4] % What I really want
```

I dont know why I get the brackets inside the list...I dont want them as I explained up.
To finish it I also need to take care about more cases:

If `P` is higher than the second list lenght, `L1` will be inserted at the end of `L2`.

If we insert a non-empty list in an empty list (no matters `P`), we will get the inserted list.

If we insert an empty list in a non-empty list (no matters `P`), we will get the non-empty list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easy thing to do would be to add `flatten` to your `insert_at` predicate. However, the root cause is that your `remove_at` is designed for single elements `X`, not lists of elements. Have you tried rewriting `remove_at` to manage `X` as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick-fix solution:

```
insert_at(X, L, K, R) :-
    remove_at(X, R1, K, L),
    flatten(R1, R).
```

The solution involving rewriting `remove_at` to manage a list:

```
remove_at([], Y, _, Y) :- !.       % added as a list base case
remove_at(_, [], _, []) :- !.      % added as a list base case
remove_at([X|T], [X|Xs], 1, L) :-  % handle a list [X|T] instead of just X
    remove_at(T, Xs, 1, L).
remove_at(X, [Y|Xs], K, [Y|Ys]) :- % same as before :)
    K > 1, 
    K1 is K - 1,
    remove_at(X, Xs, K1, Ys).

insert_at(X, L, K, R) :- remove_at(X, R, K, L).
```

The second `remove_at/4` base case says that if the list I want to remove from is empty, then the result is empty and it succeeds. That means `insert_at/4` will succeed if `K` is greater than the length of `L` and it will return the original list, `L`, as the solution.

If you want the `insert_at/4` to succeed when `K` is greater than the length of the list and instantiate `R` with `X` appended to `L` (rather than just `L` itself), you can replace `remove_at(_, [], _, []) :- !.` with `remove_at(X, X, _, []) :- !.`

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt see the change between the element and the list...I have a case is not working when I have the two lists both of them with just one element inside and the P for example is 5, I get false and what I need to get is the elements of the list...should we add a new base case?

Comment: @user3006475 if it's unable to insert, do you want the original list back? If so, then another case could be added to fix it.

Comment: Yes... it should fail. But in the exercise if P is greater than the lists length I need just to answer the elements of the lists

Comment: If P is greater than L2 lenght, L1 will be inserted at the end of L2. That is exactly the case I tried to explain you before.

Comment: @user3006475 ok, which is it? Your prior comment says if P is too large, then you get the original list back. But now you're saying you want it to append to the end of the list?

Comment: Is the second one...appending L1 at the end of L2...sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: I get this error:1 ?- insert_at([e1],[e2],5,L).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: insertar_lista/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: @user3006475 You're typing in `insertar_lista/4`. I defined `insert_at`.

Comment: 1 ?- insert_at([e1],[e2],5,L).
L = [e2]. I need as a result [e2,e1]