# Remove a sublist inside a list given a number N which indicates consecutive elements PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

I am trying to solve a Prolog exercise. It says that it works if F is the result of removing from I the number of elements as N says starting in the position P.
I have some base cases to solve as well:

- If the starting position(P) is greater than the initial list(I) length then we get I.
- If the quantity of elements to remove(N) is greater than the number of elements in the  list 
  from the given position(P), it will remove all the elements until the end, giving as a
  result an empty list.
- If the quantity of elements to remove(N) is zero the the result is I.

Here some examples:

```
?- remove_at([],7,3,F).% working
F = []
?- remove_at([k1,k2], 5, 3,F).%working
F=[k1,k2]
?- remove_at([k1,k2], 2, 5,F).%need help
F=[k1]
?- remove_at([k1,k2,k3,k4,k5], 1, 2,F).%need help
F=[k3,k4,k5]
```

The code I have, it is not working at all, just need help in the 2 cases I pointed up:

```
remove_at([],_,N,[]):-!.                  % for the base case
remove_at( Xs , _ , 0 , Xs ).             % both counts are done to zero: we're done.
remove_at( [X|Xs] , P , N , [X|Ys] ) :-   % otherwise...
P > 0 ,                                   % - when P > 0
P1 is P-1 ,                               % - decrement P
remove_at(Xs,P1,N,Ys).                    % - recurse down , adding the head of the     source list to the result list                                     
remove_at( [X|Xs] , 0 , N , Ys ) :-       % otherwise...
N > 0 ,                                   % - when N is > 0
N1 is N-1 ,                               % - decrement N
remove_at( Xs , 0 , N1 , Ys ).            % recurse down, discarding the head of the source list.
```

Comment: The definition of the arguments in your example code doesn't line up at all with your problem statement. Your problem statement says the second and third arguments should be the start index and the count, respectively. But you sample has a list element as the second argument, not the start index. I think you need to take another shot at a starting point. Think through it logically: you need a base case for `remove_at` which operates on an empty list, or deals with the third argument being =< 0, or something like that. What you have now, though, is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Side note: you're not allowed to have a space between a predicate name and the parenthetical arguments. So I've edited your post accordingly.

Comment: Your latest version of `remove_at` accepts only 3 arguments, but your examples all require four.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicholas has the right idea. Here's a corrected version:

```
% Removing items from empty list is empty list
remove_at([], _, _, []).

% Remove 0 items gives the same list back
remove_at(L, _, 0, L).

% To remove items starting at location P, allow the head of the input
% to be in the output, and remove items starting at location P-1 in the tail.
remove_at([X|T], P, N, [X|R]) :-
    P > 1,
    P1 is P-1,
    remove_at(T, P1, N, R).

% Primary case: remove items starting at current position 1
% Remove the head, then remove N-1 items from the tail.
remove_at([_|T], 1, N, R) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    remove_at(T, 1, N1, R).
```

Comment: It works for all the cases, I tried all the chances, just perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @user3006475 cool. You should study it to make sure you understand how it works. This is very similar to the insert_at we did a few days ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830333/insert-a-list-into-another-list-given-a-position-p-prolog).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this covers all your base cases, but you could approach it like this:

```
remove_at( Xs , 0 , 0 , Xs ) .            % both counts are done to zero: we're done.
remove_at( [X|Xs] , P , N , [X|Ys] ) :-   % otherwise...
  P > 0 ,                                 % - when P > 0
  P1 is P-1 ,                             % - decrement P
  remove_at(Xs,P1,N,Ys)                   % - recurse down , adding the head of the source list to the result list
  .                                       %
remove_at( [X|Xs] , 0 , N , Ys ) :-       % otherwise...
  N > 0 ,                                 % - when N is > 0
  N1 is N-1 ,                             % - decrement N
  remove_at( Xs , 0 , N1 , Ys )           % recurse down, discarding the head of the source list.
  .
```

Or you could break it down into smaller problems, list the following. We create a helper predicate (`partition/4`) that splits a list into a prefix of, at most, the specified length and the suffix, consisting of whatever is left over.

The rest is easy: we invoke `partition/4` prefix to get the prefix we want to keep, and its remainder, then we partition the remainder into its prefix, the elements we want to discard and its suffix, the tail elements we want to keep, then append the prefix we want to keep with the suffix we want to keep, yielding the result list.

```
remove_at( Xs , P , N , Ys ) :-
  partition(Xs,P,Pfx,Ts) ,       % split the source list into a prefix (Pfx) of [at most] length P and a suffix (Ts), consisting of the remainder.
  partition(Ts,N,_,Sfx) ,        % partition that suffix into a prefix (_) of [at most] length N (the elements to discard) and a suffix (Sfx) consisting of the remainder.
  append( Pfx, Sfx , Ys )        % append Pfx and Sfx to create the result list (Ys).
  .                              % Easy!

partition( Xs , 0 , [] , Xs ) .         % success if the count is down to zero: finalize the prefix.
partition( [X|Xs] , N , [X|T] , R ) :-  % otherwise...
  N > 0 ,                               % - when N > 0
  N1 is N-1 ,                           % - decrement N
  partition( Xs , N1 , T , R )         % - recurse down, prepending the head of the source list to the prefix.
  .
```

There's more than one way to do it as they say.

Comment: In your first solution (I didn't try the second) `remove_at([],7,3,F).` returns "false". His requirement is that it return `F = []`. `remove_at([k1,k2], 5, 3,F).` also returns false, but the expected result is `[k1,k2]`. You need an additional base case for the empty list, and the second argument to your existing base case should be `_`.

Comment: The result in the three first solutions is false...and in the forth one is [k1,k4,k5] instead of [k3,k4,k5]... Im trying to understand your code and trying to fix it as well

Comment: @user3006475 if you think you've figured out the answer, then you are allowed on SO to answer your own question. :) Or, if you have made changes and have further questions, you can update your original question.

Comment: ok, I edit my question...but I need some more  help to finish it